# What use are Steam Trading Cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

Is it purely a 'gotta-have-them-all' mindset, or do they actually serve some purpose?

I notice that you are able to sell them on a community market. For a test I listed one, and someone bought it for 50p. Not exactly a huge amount, but I don't understand why someone would spend real money on them.

Am I missing something?

Are they redeemable for games or money off vouchers or something 'tangible' that I'm missing?

Comment: People *buy* them for 50p? Woohoo, time to make £2.50 from my vast collection!

Comment: The amount they sell for on the market varies greatly depending on the game. For example a lot of cards fetch a massive 7p. Still, every little helps.

Comment: A bit of both I'd venture.

Answer (score 21):

Crafting a badge from a full set of cards gives

- The badge (which gives Steam XP, which in turn gives Steam Level and therefore friend list slots)
- A Steam Store coupon
- An emoticon
- A profile background

So, yes, there is quite some use to the cards. Whether or not it is worth it is an entirely different *discussion*.

Comment: Crafting badges for Steam Vouchers is probably the only real-world benefit. Unless you want to play the markets buying cards, crafting badges and selling the profile desktops and other goodies you get as a reward.

Comment: @DavidYell I'd agree, but judging from what I've read, some people really need the friend slots as well, so, to each their own, I guess. :)

Comment: @DavidYell . yes I suppose extra friend slots might have a real world use.

Comment: @Rob Most rewards are social fluff

Comment: Hey, I want this extra friend slot!

Comment: What's this friend slot thing? Does Steam tell you how many friends you're supposed to have at max?

Comment: @Zommuter By default, there is a cap on the friends list at ... I think it's 250 people. Every level grants a few more slots.

Comment: @FEichinger Gee, does one really need 250 _permanent_ "friends"?

Comment: @Zommuter I have no idea, but I'm not gonna judge. It's what it is, simple as that.

Comment: @FEichinger Agreed. It's still weird though... But then again, it's [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Have_0_Friends) with [Facebook](http://www.southparkstudios.com/full-episodes/s14e04-you-have-0-friends)

Comment: An unlisted benefit of crafting the cards is that doing so increases the chance of random card and booster pack drops - the higher your level, the greater a chance you have of getting such a drop.

Answer (score 12):

I attempted to give a high level 3-question quiz about why you would care about Steam Trading Cards [in this article](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/should-i-care-about-steam-trading-cards/):

> 1. **Are you excited about cosmetic customization elements in games?** For instance, do you spend a long time getting your character’s face just right in Skyrim, or do you like picking out and wearing hats in Team Fortress 2?
> 2. **Do you find yourself comparing your Steam account to other people’s?**  For instance, do you look at their achievements or their profile and say “I am SO much better than them!”
> 3. **Do you think a few dollars is worth a minimal effort?** If I told you that you could potentially make ~$5 today in Steam Store credit through Steam Trading Cards, would you be excited?

These correspond to the basic benefits of the cards:

1. Cosmetic elements like badges, emoticons, and profile backgrounds
2. Steam profile prestige, a few minor ancillary benefits (ie, friends list expansion)
3. Perhaps a small chance of making a few easy bucks.

If those things are important, then you're likely to want to learn more about the trading cards, but if they aren't, you're probably safe ignoring them.

Comment: From a purely economic perspective, I'm not sure it's really worth selling at the current (sub-$0.25) prices - they're kind of rock bottom given all the new supply.  I probably wouldn't buy more, but collecting them is easy and free, so holding them seems fine.