# How many friend slots do you start off with, and how many do you get per Steam level?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

According to [What use are Steam Trading Cards?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124006/what-use-are-steam-trading-cards), additional Steam levels grants extra friend slots. Given that I have as many Steam friends as there are fingers on my hand, I didn't realize there was a limit in the first place, so in the interest of finding out how useful gaining a Steam level actually is, how many slots do each level grant you?

Comment: For clarification: are you counting your thumbs as fingers?

Comment: I had like 50 friends tops, and I cleaned out like 40 of those who I forgot were. As of now, only people I know IRL are on my friends list. Cause who the hell has 250 friends?

Comment: @user1337 Those of us who use the friends feature to find players we enjoy gaming with - L4D2 makes it a central aspect of the game - so in my case, it's not _friends_ it's people I game with more than once or twice a month. Bearing in mind that some matches require 8 players online and willing to play, a decent-sized pool is required to get a game.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As per [this Steam forums thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3122809), and [this Community discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/828939163918434154/):

By default, you have a limit of **250** people for your friends list and every level adds another **5** slots - which means that you get 50 slots per milestone (10, 20, etc).

In addition to that, *linking a Facebook account* adds another **50** slots - to a base of 300.

Answer (score 5):

According to the bottommost entry of [*this page*](http://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9942-YUOM-5443#limit), the initial limit is 250 and the answer to "*What do I get when I craft a badge from my Trading Cards?*" on [*this page*](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq/) says that each level increases the limit by 5.