# Earning "Friends List Slot" on Steam, what does this mean?

Tags: steam

After I crafted a badge, I receive this a "5 slot level bonus".

**Does anyone know what it means ?**

[image: Screenshot of the 5 slot bonus]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your Friends-list now has 5 more slots for 5 more friends.

Comment: ^ Didn't know there was a limit ! What's the default one ?

Comment: @Galabyca Honestly, I don't even know. I've been a user for too long and this was never an actual problem for me. There didn't _use to be_ any limits back in the day.

Comment: @Galabyca Friend's list limits: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124144/how-many-friend-slots-do-you-start-off-with-and-how-many-do-you-get-per-steam-l